# How to set a geolocation on a DNS record in route53 with boto

Tags: python, dns, boto, amazon-route53

I the following snip of code I'm adding a value to a change set that I'll later commit.

```
add = changes.add_change('CREATE', url, record_type, ttl=DEFAULT_TTL)
add.add_value(new_val)
```

How would I add a geolocation to the created record? I can see in the docs at [http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/route53.html#module-boto.route53.record] that I should be able to add a region for latency based routing by adding a region="blah" argument. However, I don't see any mention of geolocation. Is the library capable of handling a geolocation routing policy? Or do I just need to stick with a latency routing policy.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below snippet. Try installing boto3 by "pip install boto3"

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('route53')
response = client.change_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId='ZYMJVBD6FUN6S',
    ChangeBatch={
        'Comment': 'comment',
        'Changes': [
            {
                'Action': 'CREATE',
                'ResourceRecordSet': {
                    'Name': 'udara.com',
                    'Type': 'A',
                    'SetIdentifier': 'Africa record',
                    'GeoLocation': {
                        'ContinentCode': 'AF'
                    },
                    'TTL': 123,
                    'ResourceRecords': [
                        {
                            'Value': '127.0.0.1'
                        },
                        ],
                }
            },
            ]
    }
)
```